-webkit and -moz missing after compiling bootstrap5
I am trying to customize bootstrap5. as a start I created scss file
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
when compiled using live sass compiler and compared with original bootstrap, -webkit and -moz are missing.
what am I missing?
Since no variables or configurations are altered, I am expecting exact bootstrap5 replica css

How are you compiling Sass? For VS Code, in the settings for Live Sass Compiler, there is a setting "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": that can be set to true.

Thanks for direction.
After setting to true, it needed browsesrlist, so I copied ".browserslistrc" fist from bootstrap project "link"
